# GridView did not have any properties or attributes from with to generate columns

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, gridview

This is the oddest error I've ever encountered as it makes no sense to.  I'm getting an IList from my controller.  I can even write a foreach loop and append TicketId to a stringbuilder and display my results.

I can put in break points and see that I have the expected results returned....as EXPECTED!  All values in place (no-misspellings as I've even copy & pasted)

But if I try to bind it to a GridView or repeater I get the error: **The data source for GridView with id 'gv' did not have any properties or attributes from which to generate columns**

example - in this code If I comment out the DataBinding to the gridview gv - I get the results as of the TicketId's as epxected:

```
LeadController controller = new LeadController();
        var leads = controller.SearchProducts(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-50),
                                                       DateTime.Now, string.Empty, string.Empty);

        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (LeadDto lead in (leads))
        {
            sb.Append(string.Format("{0} -----", lead.TicketId));
        }
        lblTop.Text = sb.ToString();

        gv.DataSource = leads;
        gv.DataBind();
```

But if the DataBinding isn't commented - the whole page errors with the above error.
Here's my ascx

```
<asp:TextBox ID="lblTop" runat="server" /><asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" ></asp:GridView>
```

If I change my gridview as so:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" >
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField >
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%# Eval("TicketId") %>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

I get an error that says:  **DataBinding: 'DataTransferObjects.LeadDto' does not contain a property with the name 'TicketId'**.

But I can see it DOES after setting DataSource and prior to DataBinding...

I've tried shutting down VS2008 & even restarted my PC just in case it was a magic fairy bug....

Please, any suggestions?

Comment: Without seeing your LeadController class, it is hard for me to pinpoint the issue.  What does changing your binding code to gv.DataSource = leads.AsEnumerable() do?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You said the `LeadDto` object has a property named `TicketId`, but are you sure it's a *property* and not a *field*? That is, in your `LeadDto` class how is `TicketId` defined? If it's defined as a member variable then it is **not** a property:

```
public class LeadDto
{
     public int TicketId;

     ...
}
```

The databinding only can bind against *properties*:

```
public class LeadDto
{
     public int TicketId { get; set; };

     ...
}
```

Comment: Scott.... You nailed it!  That's exactly what I did.  Not sure why I didn't have it that way in the first place - as the example I'm following does...  Thank you soo much!